# Count is 0 for isnull(table_name) but there are no values for many rows in that table. How to get the correct count?

Tags: database, isnull, clickhouse

I am trying to improve the data quality and reporting accuracy by tracing and transforming empty cells in rows of a table. But, to know how many tables have no values, I used
*SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE isNull(column_name)*

This query returned 0 count which is an issue for me.
Can you provide me with a solution to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Null vs '' problem ??

```
create table TABLE_NAME(column_name Nullable(String)) Engine=Log;
insert into TABLE_NAME values(''), ('1'), (Null);

SELECT *
FROM TABLE_NAME

┌─column_name─┐
│             │
│ 1           │
│ ᴺᵁᴸᴸ        │
└─────────────┘


SELECT COUNT()
FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE isNull(column_name)

┌─COUNT()─┐
│       1 │
└─────────┘

SELECT COUNT()
FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE column_name = ''

┌─COUNT()─┐
│       1 │
└─────────┘

SELECT COUNT()
FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE coalesce(column_name, '') = ''

┌─COUNT()─┐
│       2 │
└─────────┘
```